# BEM naming from unique to repeating elements

Tags: css, bem

I have code like this

```
<div class="chatlist-container chatlist-container_hidden">
  <div class="container-header">
    <span class="chatlist-title">

    </span>
    <div class="container-header__button">
    <span class="icon-minus"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="container-header__button">
      <span class="icon-cancel"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <dl class="chatlist-container__chatlist">
      <div class="chatlist-container__chatgroup">
          <p ...
          <div ...
      </div>
      <div class="chatlist-container__chatgroup">

      </div>
      <div class="chatlist-container__chatgroup">

      </div>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Where `chatlist-container` is a main container, then goes `container-header` , which can be reused in another containers, so he named without dependency `chatlist-container__`, then goes `chatlist-container__chatlist`, which exists only inside `chatlist-container` so he named with his dependency, and then goes `chatlist-container__chatgroup`, groups which can repeat but only exists inside `chatlist-container`, how to name their childs, with or withoud dependency of `chatlist-container` ?

I imagine this like `chatlist-container__chatgroup-title` and  `chatlist-container__chatgroup-description`, right? But if so, if `description` will have and childs later, their naming can be very tricky and long.

Also, if so, how to write css, now it looks like:

`.chatlist-container { ...
.chatlist-container .chatlist-container__chatlist { ...
.chatlist-container .chatlist-container__chatlist .chatlist-container__chatgroup { ...`

But if i add child elements to my groups, their selectors are getting kilometer long, and looks like this

`.chatlist-container .chatlist-container__chatlist .chatlist-container__chatgroup .chatlist-container__chatgroup-title { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different approach to the naming could be taken, if you so desired.
You mentioned that other containers exist, and that `chatlist_container` is only one type of a container, which makes me think that perhaps there should be a `container` class somewhere with the chatlist version being a modifier, i.e. `container--chatlist`.

Also, in my opinion, just because `chatgroup` currently only exists within the chatlist container doesn't mean that it has to have the container's name prefixed to it. Giving it a name like `chatgroup` allows it to be used outside of the container at some point perhaps. Then any of its children only need to have `chatgroup` prefixed to their names.

This is not an answer, as you know what you are building far more than any of us here, but perhaps these thoughts might lead you to rethinking the current naming scheme and thus making things easier for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i just wanted to hear other opinions than mine, so your answer perfectly fits, more of this i had thoughts about naming chatgroup as standalone component, just wanted to know if somebody thinks so too, and will it be understandable and easy to support not only for me.

Answer (score 1):

If maintainability is the issue, i'd suggest using a preprocessors such as [sass](http://sass-lang.com/) would help out.. Sass has a functionality with nesting and using the & sign to avoid long rules, pseudo example code:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;

    .b-header {
        display: flex;
        background: #F5F5F5;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 0 2rem;
        margin-top: 2rem;

        &__about {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 2rem;
            word-wrap: break-word;

            .title {
                font-size: calc(1.5rem + 3vw);
                margin-bottom: 5rem;
            }

            .job {
                font-size: calc(1.8rem + 3vw);
                margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
            }

            .cv {
                display: inline-block;  
                font-size: calc(0.5rem + 3vw);
                margin: 3rem 0;
            }
        }

        &__image {
            img {
                min-width: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you, i am working with sass, but for this project i have strict requirement for vanilla CSS, without preprocessors and stuff.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate =/.